# Add a block from Gutenberg Nightly to a custom template

Tags: theme-development, block-editor

I installed the Gutenberg Nightly plugin from [Gutenberg Times](https://gutenbergtimes.com/need-a-zip-from-master/). I'm trying to access the Table of Contents block to put it into a custom taxonomy page template that I'm building. My first instinct was to try something like this using the `render_block` function ([link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/render_block/)):

```php
// Render Gutenberg Table of Contents block
  $table_of_contents_block = [
    'blockName' => 'core/table-of-contents',
    'attributes' => [],
  ];
  echo render_block($table_of_contents_block);
```

This is not working, so I am questioning whether it is even a valid way to do this. Do I need to go as far as registering a template like documented [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-templates/)? I can add already add Table of Contents to any post or custom post type visually via the Gutenberg editor, so to me it seems like that means the plugin is already doing this.

What is the correct way to add a block from Gutenberg Nightly to a page template using Gutenberg Times plugin?